# Difference between call and execution in AOP

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I'm trying to understand the difference between execution and call in AOP as simply as possible. From what I gather, execution() will add a join point in the executing code, so `HelloWorldSayer.sayHello()` in this case, but if the pointcut was `call()`, then the join point will be `HelloWorldSayer.main()`. Is this correct?

```
public class HelloWorldSayer {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        sayHello();
    }

    public static void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

public aspect World {
    public hello():
        execution(static void HelloWorldSayer.sayHello());

    after() hello() {
        System.out.println("Bye");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [execution Vs. call Join point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132822/execution-vs-call-join-point)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we look at the `HelloWorldSayer` class again, there are 4 join point shadows (2 execution pointcuts and 2 call pointcuts).

In other words, `public static void main (String[] args)` and `public static void sayHello()` refer to the execution pointcut. `(HelloWorldSayer.)sayHello();` and `System.out.println("Hello");` refer to the call pointcut.

If you change the declared pointcut as follows, the pointcut selects `sayHello();`

```
public pointcut hello():
    call(static void HelloWorldSayer.sayHello());
```

On the other hand,  you change the declared pointcut as follows, the pointcut selects the sayHello method declaration `public static void sayHello()`.

```
public pointcut hello():
    execution(static void HelloWorldSayer.sayHello());
```

At last, please read this answer to get better understanding about `call()` and `execution()`:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18149106/904745