# Aspect using pointcut=@annotation for @AfterThrowing is running twice

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I'm facing a strange behaviour using AspectJ for a pointcut using my custom annotation.

The pointcut I use is:

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut="@annotation(com.core.meta.NotifyOnFailure)", throwing="ex")
```

The problem I have is that my aspect is executed twice but if I modify the pointcut to:

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut="execution(* sendAndReceive(..))", throwing="ex")
```

It runs once as expected.

The only method I have that raises the aspect is this:

```
    @NotifyOnFailure // I want to use this annotation to raise the aspect once
    public  String sendAndReceive(String serviceUrl)
    {
         String responseXml = "...";
         try
         {
             throw new Exception("test...");
         }
         catch(Exception x)
         {
            ExternalExecutionException ex = new ExternalApiExecutionException("Service failed");
            throw ex; 
         }
         finally
         {
             ...
         }          

        return responseXml;
    }
```

Any idea about why my aspect is executed twice when using my custom annotation and only once when I use `execution` pointcut?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you also restrict the pointcut to *execution*. Otherwise it will only be restricted to the annotation and thus be used for both *call* and *execution* (if AspectJ can advise the call of your method, which it can since it is in your own code). A good comparison between both is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18149106/2191746

Your pointcut would then look like this:

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut="execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(com.core.meta.NotifyOnFailure)", throwing="ex")
```

No guarantee on the syntax, as I don't have an aspectJ compiler at hand.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this, you helped me a lot with this. +1

Comment: No problem. Keep trucking with AspectJ, it's worth it. :)