# Poincut not well-formed

Tags: java, aspectj

Imagine that, in an application I'm developing, there is a need to sort each of
the returning objects, from any method with these characteristics:

- the method is inside the package my.sorted or any of its subpackages
- the returning object implements the List interface
- the method has the @Sorted annotation

I want to create an Aspect called SortingAspect in which implements:

- A pointcut for the desired points of interruption
- An advice to perform the intended functionality

With this case I came to this code:

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass {

    @Sorted
    public List<Integer> myFunction(){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(20);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(-4);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(200);
        list.add(34);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Sorted.

```
public @interface Sorted {

}
```

SortedAspect:

```
@Aspect
public class SortingAspect {
    @Pointcut ("call(* my.sorted..* (..)) && @annotation(Sorted)")
    public void sortFuncPointCut() {}

    @Around("sortFuncPointCut()")
    public List<Integer> sortAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>)pjp.proceed();
        Collections.sort(list);
        return list;
    }

}
```

Problem:
The problem is that the @Around is not catch any Poincut and I can not understand why.

Comment: how you build you code and what agent do you use when run it ?

Comment: @sbjavateam This is a AspectJ project and what I do is, in eclipse IDE, click on the project and build it. About the agent, I'm not understanding what you mean.

Comment: Is there a reason to use call instead of execution? That way you define the call to come from the package my.sorted..., not the called method to reside in it. Thus a class outside of my.sorted... calling one inside that package structure will not be advised.

Comment: @sheltem there is no reason. Want I want is, at the final of any method execution with the characteristics described, I could sort the result of the function, and send back to proceed with the normal flow. So, you are telling me that if I change it to "execution" this may work?

Comment: It won't work yet, because *I think* you are not referencing the annotation correctly either, but it will get you closer to what you want. I don't have time for a complete answer now, but have a look at the difference between call and execution for now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132822/execution-vs-call-join-point/18149106#18149106

Comment: The annotation is correct because I test the same pointcut only with the annotation code. And thank you for the help

Comment: Just tried it out myself. So long as your Sorted annotation has runtime-retention just switching to an execution Pointcut should work. Have you tried with execution?

Comment: @sheltem Yes, and is not working :S. Afternoon I will put more info like the package structure etc.