# AOP AspectJ Pointcut if() throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to write an Aspect, trying to implement Pointcut's if() condition but receiving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. here is the code snippet.

```
@Pointcut("call(* com.aop.Service.activate(..)) && args(iActivate,..) && if()")
    public static boolean saveActivate(Activate iActivate) {
        return true; //if false @before she not be invoked
    };

@Before("saveActivate(iActivate)")
    public void saveActivateBefore(JoinPoint ijoinPoint, ActivateInstallmentRequest iActivateInstallmentRequest) {
        System.out.println("Log from @before");    
}
```

This code is giving me below exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapperConfigurer' defined in class path resource [springfox/documentation/spring/web/SpringfoxWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
```

Can Someone help me what I'm missing here?
PS: I have also referred [AspectJ](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html#d0e3697).

Comment: Before we proceed, I want to double-check: Are you 100% sure you use AspectJ and not just Spring AOP? Did you explicitly configure Spring to use load-time weaving? Another question is if your target class name really is `com.aop.service` with a lower-case "s". Usually Java class names start with a capital letter.

Comment: @kriegaex - I'm using Spring AOP in my project. Based on yu comment, I assume conditional if for a Pointcut in only for AspectJ but not Spring AOP?
"com.aop.service" is an arbitrary name I've given in the code, no need to concern about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having verified that you use Spring AOP,  the answer is indeed that both `if()` and `call()` are not supported, see also the Spring manual section about [pointcut designators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators).

If you want to use those designators, you need to activate [AspectJ via LTW (load-time weaving)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj).

A workaround for Spring AOP would be to simply use a regular `if` at the beginning of your advice method and, if there are no specific reasons for using `call()`, use `execution()` instead, which is what most people want anyway. I am not going to elaborate about the difference between call and execution joinpoints here, but you can e.g. consult [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18149106/1082681) for more information.

---

**Update:** There are other things which look a little bit strange in your code snippet, but what I explained is the biggest issue for now.